# How to use simple function in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, autoloader

I'd like to use a simple function in Symfony 4, something like this :

**src/Service/Utils.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Service;

/**
 * @param string $attr
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function attributNilTrue($attr): bool
{
    return json_encode($attr) === '{"@attributes":{"nil":"true"}}';
}
```

**some/other/file.php**

```php
use function App\Service\attributNilTrue;

if (attributNilTrue($foo['bar'])) {
    // Do something...
}
```

But I get the following error:

> The autoloader expected class "App\Service\Utils" to be defined in file  "/var/www/interop/vendor/composer/../../src/Service/Utils.php". The
>   file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace  probably has a typo.

Is there a way to do that without having to create a `Utils` class?

Comment: Basically no.  Php does not support autoloading for functions.  A static class function is really your best bet.  Or figure out the best spot to use a require statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [autoloader `files` key in composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files).

In your `composer.json` file include something like this:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "files": ["src/utility_functions.php"]
    }
}
```

(where `src/utility_functions.php` is a file containing your function definitions).

Dump your autoloader (`composer dump-autoload`) so this is incorporated into your autoloader files, and whatever functions you define in this file will be available on each request.

Your typical Sf4 will already include a PSR4 entry there, so you will have to add your own. The end result would look more or less like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "src/"
    },
    "files": [
      "src/utility_functions.php"
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to wrap such functions in class - for example:

```
namespace App\Service;

class Utils
{
    /**
     * @param string $attr
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function attributNilTrue($attr): bool
    {
        return \json_encode($attr) === '{"@attributes":{"nil":"true"}}';
    }
}
```

If you have autoloading configured for that directory then it should be loaded automatically - otherwise add service definition like this:

```
App\Service\Utils:
```

Then you can use it like:

```
use App\Service\Utils;

...

if (Utils::attributNilTrue($foo['bar'])) {
    // Do something...
}
```

This way:

1. Your class is correctly defined according to PSR4 (https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) :

   ```
   2.3.3:
   The terminating class name corresponds to a file name ending in .php. The file name MUST match the case of the terminating class name.
   ```
2. You dont need to mess with composer.
3. When in future you will need some dependecies inside those functions/methods then you can easily inject them because it is a service.